# Why is setDelegate not working for UITextFieldDelegate, but working via Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have the following code below, and I can't figure out why the `textFieldShouldReturn` method is not being called. When I use IB to create the connection to the delegate, it works, but when done programmatically, the log statement is not being displayed. What am I doing wrong here?

Secondly, in the `textFieldShouldReturn`, some examples return `YES`, and some return `NO`. The ios documentation specified that returning `YES` would provide default implementation. Can someone please explain this in more detail?

//`.h` file

```
@interface GoSocietyLoginController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {    
}
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;

@end
```

//`.m` file

```
@interface GoSocietyLoginController ()

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField   *login;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField   *password;

@end


@implementation GoSocietyLoginController

@synthesize login;
@synthesize password;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {    
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [login setDelegate:self];
        [password setDelegate:self];
    }

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
        NSLog(@"Hello World");

        if ([textField isEqual:login]) {
            [password becomeFirstResponder];
        }

        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: I have also just tried:

self.login.delegate = self;
self.password.delegate = self;

still doesn't work

Comment: Figured it out, I'm new to iphone development, so this may be obvious to most of you. I didn't create a connection emanating from my file owner to the text fields - I thought they only had to be done the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you've posted, it does not appear to me that you have declared the outlets in your header:

```
IBOutlet UITextField *login;
IBOutlet UITextField *password;
```

Be sure to declare them and set up the connections in the IB.

Comment: Thanks, they were there originally as part of a class extension, and I added them to the question.

Comment: I still don't see them declared.

Comment: They are part of a private category in your implementation, I think they need to be moved to your interface definition in the header.

Comment: Yes, they were declared as a class extension in the implementation as "private" members. I will try and move them to the interface definition ".h" file and try it.

Comment: Moving them to the header file made no difference.